# How can I set http method in servlet filter(in context of Spring Framework)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, filter, http-method

I have got a such issue: I do have got antMatcher​ in `Spring Security`. And I have an opportunity to set http method `GET/POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE` for url mapping for my filter. So requests with some methods will be filtered with my filter if they have certain methods and will not be filtered otherways. But how can I specify http method without Spring Security? Is it possible to do it somehow in a cool way using `FilterRegistrationBean` or I will be have to use

```
switch(request.getMethod()) {
   ...
}
```

in my fileter doFilterInternal() method (I use OncePerRequestFilter) and act according to which method is specified in HttpServletRequest? That is tedious, isn`t it?

I tried to find out some info according to this issue and researches have not been successful yet.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomFilter> registrationBean(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<CustomFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(customFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/open/*");
    /*may be it is possible to addHttpMethods?*/
    registration.setName("customLoggingFilter");
    registration.setOrder(2);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: No you cannot (unless you implement it in the filter). The servlet API only has the ability to filter on URL (pattern) and not on anything else.

Comment: You can always make a filter that takes an `AntMatcher` (that is a class) and then override the `shouldFilter` method of the `OncePerRequestFilter` (that is basically also what Spring Security uses for its filters).

Comment: Thank you. Not bad idea for my task. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no. It is impossible, but I was told that it is a really not bad idea to override the `shouldFilter` method of the `OncePerRequestFilter`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).